# AIR / Flash Fullscreen across multiple monitors as one window?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, multiple-monitors

We have 4 monitors arranged 2 x 2. Are there any ways to enable the new release of AIR to expand across all monitors in one window?

Alternatively is there any software that can trick it the display driver to show only one large monitor?

Comment: What happens if you resize the main window to the total resolution of the 2x2 grid and position it in the top left corner of the top left monitor?

Comment: unfortunately we don't have multiple monitors here at the moment, I'm tasked with ordering in, once we know what might work.

Comment: Then I'll be lazy too and answer: yes, it's probably possible. (Come on, you just have to plug in an additional monitor and try it)

Comment: haha - seriously we just have single hi res monitors in the office

Comment: No spares, really? If your boss would like to pay me to do your research for you, I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for [flash.display.Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html).

Once you figure out how big it should be, you should be able to set its position and size using the `bounds` property off the [flash.display.NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) class.

**Update:**

So here at work I have two monitors, so I threw together a quick test AIR app:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.Screen;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class MultimonitorTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function MultimonitorTest()
        {
            var screens:Array = Screen.screens;
            var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();

            for(var i:uint;i<screens.length;i++) {
                trace(Screen(screens[i]).bounds);
                rect = rect.union(screens[i].bounds);
            }
            trace(rect);
            this.stage.nativeWindow.bounds = rect;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it loops through the available screens. It also creates a new rectangle that is a union of the composite screens. Then sets `nativeWindow.bounds` to that union.

The output of the app is this:

```
(x=0, y=0, w=1440, h=900)
(x=1440, y=0, w=1920, h=1080)
(x=0, y=0, w=3360, h=1080)
```

One thing to consider is this doesn't take into account the taskbar or anything else, and if your screens are different sizes, like mine are, the resulting rectangle will be larger than your actual screens. But this should at least give you a place to start.

So, to answer your question: Yes. :)

Comment: Cool, is this something you have experienced working? I know how big it should be 3840 x 2160 (4 x HD)... just cant test before ordering. Cant even try on a dual monitor set up at the mo.

Comment: awesome cheers! I really need to push a for a room of spares - so we can actually R&D properly!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a much simpler way to accomplish this - just set the stage to the size required, and in application.xml set `<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>`